# jQuery. Pause video with timeout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, html5-video

I have several videos on my site that have the same class.

I want to play only one video when hovering over it. As soon as I removed the hover, the video was paused with a delay of 1 second.

I learned how to start a video and pause it. But as soon as I add setTimeout I get an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pause')`

Below I am attaching the html code of my solution:

```
<a href="#" class="cases__item">
   <video class="cases__item-video" playsinline="true" loop="" preload="metadata" src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4"></video>
</a>

<a href="#" class="cases__item">
   <video class="cases__item-video" playsinline="true" loop="" preload="metadata" src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4"></video>
</a>

<a href="#" class="cases__item">
   <video class="cases__item-video" playsinline="true" loop="" preload="metadata" src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4"></video>
</a>
```

Also I am attaching the html code of my solution:

```
            var figure = $(".cases__item").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

            function hoverVideo(e) {
                $('.cases__item-video', this).get(0).play();
            }

            function hideVideo(e) {
                setTimeout(function (){
                    $('.cases__item-video', this).get(0).pause();
                }, 1000);
            }
```

I also add working jsfiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/v7certb6/1/

Please help me to resolve the video pause issue after one second.

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `this` in the `setTimeout()` function handler refers to that function, not to the element reference provided in the invocation of the outer `hoverVideo()` or `hideVideo()` functions.

To fix this issue create a variable in the outer scope to retain the reference to `this` which you use within the `setTimeout()`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="cases__item">
  <video class="cases__item-video" playsinline="true" loop="" preload="metadata" src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4"></video>
</a>

<a href="#" class="cases__item">
  <video class="cases__item-video" playsinline="true" loop="" preload="metadata" src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4"></video>
</a>

<a href="#" class="cases__item">
  <video class="cases__item-video" playsinline="true" loop="" preload="metadata" src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4"></video>
</a>
```

```js
var figure = $(".cases__item").hover(hoverVideo, hideVideo);

function hoverVideo(e) {
    let _this = this;
  $('.cases__item-video', _this).get(0).play();
}

function hideVideo(e) {
  let _this = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.cases__item-video', _this).get(0).pause();
  }, 1000);
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/670xhuL9/) - note the example is in a fiddle as the cross-site content has issues when played on the main SO site.

As a side note, the JS can be reduced to the following, which has the exact same behaviour just using arrow functions:

```js
$(".cases__item").hover(
  e => e.currentTarget.querySelector('.cases__item-video').play(), 
  e => setTimeout(() => e.currentTarget.querySelector('.cases__item-video').pause(), 1000));
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped a lot. Your solution is perfect for my case.